# Is there a strong evidence, that the Zeeman conjecture is false?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

In a lot of articles I have read, that the Zeeman Conjecture implies the Andrews-Curtis-Conjecture and if we disprove the AC-Conjecture then Zeeman is obviously also false (as the sources state). But what makes mathematicians think, that the Zeeman Conjecture could possibly be false?

Are there any (functioning) links to articles arguing about this question?

Answer (score 5):

Here is one [counter argument by Sergei Matveev:](https://books.google.nl/books?id=vFLgAyeVSqAC&pg=PA57#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]

Comment: thanks for that post, but I searched evidence not particular from AC-Conjecture but more from thoughts about collapsibilty