# What is the latest progress on the Andrews-Curtis Conjecture?

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Out of curiosity . . .

> What is the latest progress on the [Andrews-Curtis Conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrews%E2%80%93Curtis_conjecture)?

What's available online seems limited. (See the Wikipedia article linked to above.)

I found the following [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/375407/42153):

[image]

Here ZC is the [Zeeman Conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_conjecture) and PC is the [Poincaré conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture).

**My Background:** I did an MPhil in combinatorial group theory. It ended in 2022. See my profile for more.